# WINDOWS Could not build wheels for pyodbc, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, django, pip

Hello I having problems with this error:

"Could not build wheels for pyodbc, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects"

I don't know what to do!
I searched and installed pyproject.toml and nothing!

asgiref                   3.7.2

attrs                     23.1.0

Django                    4.2.7

jsonschema                4.20.0

jsonschema-specifications 2023.11.1

mssql-django              1.3

pip                       23.3.1

pyodbc                    5.0.1

pyproject-toml            0.0.10

pytz                      2023.3.post1

referencing               0.31.0

rpds-py                   0.13.1

setuptools                69.0.2

sqlparse                  0.4.4

toml                      0.10.2

tzdata                    2023.3

wheel                     0.41.3

Python 3.12.0